# How to send a string using Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, asp.net-mvc-3, stream

I am looking at an example of a Stream used to transfer data, I would like to pass an additional string'infoAsString'

```
string infoAsString = "blablabla";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
            request.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {      
                //pass infoAsString?
                requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

                requestStream.Close();
            }
```

//then I can grab it..

```
public object Upload(string infoAsString)
    {
```

please advise....thanks for any replies

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.Headers` collection for this:

```
string infoAsString = "blablabla";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
request.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
request.Headers.Add(string.format("infoAsString: {0}", infoAsString))

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{      
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

    requestStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, iv tried this and in debug when code reaches the request.Headers it throws : Specified value does not have a ':' separator.
Parameter name: header

Comment: oh shure. you should separate with colon, not with comma. I update answer.